# Vector differentiations

Tags: vectors

If A and B are irrotational How to Prove that AxB is solenoidal.
Given **A**is Irrotational 
**B** is irrotational.
We have from the prooperties of irrotational vectors that if any vector is irrotational we have **div**.V equals to zero and there exists a scalar point function phi that F=Del phi
So we have
 1. A=del phi
 2. B =Del Psi

Comment: Use MathJax for better formatting

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities)
$$
{\rm div}(A\times B) = ({\rm curl\ }A)\cdot B - A\cdot({\rm curl\ }B).
$$